# Fatal Error @EnvironmentObject not working

Tags: object, swiftui, environment

I have 2 Views but I cannot get the Data Flow to work with the Picker with @Environment Object, I always get fatal error with a crash, but I already declared environmentobject in the Preview and in the ResultView.

First View looks like this

```
import SwiftUI

@MainActor class DataExample : ObservableObject {
    @Published var testnumber = "Test"
    
}

struct PickerView: View {
    
   @StateObject var data = DataExample()
   
    
    var body: some View {
      
        VStack {
            Picker(
                selection: $data.testnumber,
                label: Text("PickerName"),
                content: {
                    
                    Text("John").tag("John")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Freddy").tag("Freddy")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Becky").tag("Becky")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                      
                })
           
            
            .frame(width: 120, height: 45)
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            
               
        }
        .environmentObject(data)
       
    }
}
    
struct PickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PickerView()
           
    }
}
```

Second View looks like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerResultView: View {
  
    @EnvironmentObject var data : DataExample
   
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            PickerView()
            Text("\(data.testnumber)")
            .environmentObject(data)
            
                
            }
       
        }
       
}

struct PickerResultView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PickerResultView()
            .environmentObject(DataExample())
    }
}
```

Maybe somebody can point to my problem.

Comment: The selection doesn’t match the picker content

Comment: Hi Joakim, what do I need to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: And you have mixed up when to use StateObject and EnvironmentObject

Comment: Could you maybe write it in the code, I tried to rewrite it what you said, but don't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is the example above using an environment object. The object must be at the top of the view hierarchy that will access it. As an example, I placed it at the ContentView level but it could be lower depending on the app. The environment object is creating the shared instance:

```
@main
struct yourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(DataExample())
        }
    }
}
```

This is the example code modified to access the environment object above. The two views, PickerView and PickerResultView, can be used independently:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ResultsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Result", systemImage: "folder")
                }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ResultsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.teal.ignoresSafeArea()
            PickerResultView()
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea()
            PickerView()
        }
    }
}


@MainActor class DataExample : ObservableObject {
    @Published var testnumber = "Test"
}


struct PickerView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var data: DataExample

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Picker(
                selection: $data.testnumber,
                label: Text("PickerName"),
                content: {
                    
                    Text("John").tag("John")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Freddy").tag("Freddy")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Becky").tag("Becky")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                })
            .frame(width: 120, height: 45)
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
        }
    }
}


struct PickerResultView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var data: DataExample
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(data.testnumber)")
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like this where the pickerview(in orange) is used to make a change and the change is reflected in other parts of the app(in teal):

[image]

Comment: Hi Marcy, thank you for the answer. But now I always have to have 2 Views together. I wanted to Place the Result in one view and the picker in another view. But like this, its not working...

Comment: PickerView and PickerResultView are separate views that can be placed in other views separately just as long as they are each in the environment object's view hierarchy. I only put them together in ContentView to display the results of both. For example, PickerView could be placed in a settings view and PickerResultView could be placed any other place in your app as the environment object is at the ContentView level. Please provide more details if I'm misunderstanding. :)

Comment: The code has been updated to show the views working in separate views. One view updates testnumber and the other displays testnumber. Each view is working with the environment object directly, independently of each other.

Comment: Hi Marcy, now I am a stepp further and finally with your help it works in the Canvas/Preview everything as expected, but when I start the Simulator it crashes..  Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type DataExample found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for DataExample may be missing as an ancestor of this view it points to Text("\(data.testnumber)")

Comment: Did you remember to add the environment object at a level accessible to every view that needs it? That is, like in the @main example I provided? Something that has this: ContentView().environmentObject(DataExample())

Comment: thank you very much everything works fine now I forget to put it under the parent view